# Units on a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring such that there exists units $u_1, \dots , u_p : u_1 + \dots + u_p=0$
and $p$ a prime. Did $A$ have a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ in general

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is clearly no in general. The $3$ non-zero elements of a field of order $4$ have sum zero, but there is no subring $\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Did exist a characterization of the fact " A have p units such that  $u_1 + \dots + u_p =0$ for p prime ?

Comment: I don 't know if there is a characterization, but take any field of characteristic greater than p(p-1), where p is any prime. Then 1 + 2 + ..... + (p-1) + (-p(p-1)/2) is a zero sum of p distinct units.

Answer (score 4):

An easy counterexample occurs with $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $p=2$, and $u_1=1$, $u_2=-1$.

Comment: Did exist a characterization of the fact " A have p units such that  $u_1 + \dots + u_p =0$ for p prime ?

Comment: in **any** unitary ring, $\;1+(-1)=0\,$ ...

Comment: I think $p$ is supposed to be given (not chosen) and the characterization is allowed to depend on $p$.